# Problem with getting the size of a column with SQL-Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that returns the size of a column in a particular table in my database

I am using SQL Developer environment and I am new to it

I have tried this simple code to which I applied what I found in the Internet :

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
       col1      VARCHAR2(15) PRIMARY KEY,
       col2      Number(4) NOT NULL)

select data_type, data_length 
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'tab1'
   and column_name = 'col1';
```

I expect for my second query to get this: `VARCHAR2` and `15`

But I get this :

```
no data found
```

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `'TAB1'` and `'COL1'` (using capital letters). Unless table and/or column names are given in double-quotes (which is a bad practice), names are case insensitive. However, when written to the dictionary tables, they are written in upper case letters, and that's how you must use them when you query the dictionary tables.

Answer (score 3):

You should use uppercase version of identifiers:

```
select data_type, data_length 
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = UPPER('tab1')   -- 'TAB1'
   and column_name = UPPER('col1'); -- 'COL1'
```

**[db<>fidde demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=23852876b8f4af9ed2f5cb650b19151c)**

> [Schema Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223)
>
> You can use either quoted or nonquoted identifiers to name any database object. However, database names, global database names, and database link names are always case insensitive and **are stored as *uppercase*.** If you specify such names as quoted identifiers, then the quotation marks are silently ignored.

Comment: The use of `upper()` around hard-coded values seems excessive - why not simply write `'TAB1'` and `'COL1'`? Is that how *you* query catalog tables?

Comment: @mathguy Matter of taste. It could be uppercased string literal as well.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing it worked!! Thank you all !
See you soon for the next question :D